# Codeship deployment error installing ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Not sure what it means or why it's happening, any advice appreciated massively.

```
    arning! PATH is not properly set up, '/home/rof/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin' is not at first place,
usually this is caused by shell initialization files - check them for 'PATH=...' entries,
it might also help to re-add RVM to your dotfiles: 'rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles',
to fix temporarily in this shell session run: 'rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p327'.
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-1.9.3p545.
ruby-1.9.3p545 is not installed - installing.
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-1.9.3p545.
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3p545.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-1.9.3p545.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/rof/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3p545, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
Unknown ruby string (do not know how to handle): ruby-1.9.3p545.
ruby-1.9.3p545 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3p545, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
The requested url does not exist(22): 'http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p545.tar.bz2'
Checking fallback: http://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p545.tar.bz2
Checking fallback: http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/./ruby-1.9.3p545.tar.bz2
No fallback URL could be found, try increasing timeout with:

echo "export rvm_max_time_flag=20" >> ~/.rvmrc

There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-1.9.3p545 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
```

Seems like nothing it working to get my app launched on heroku - I was launching it through github push.

The app can be found @ [www.github.com/cjshort/devonite](http://www.github.com/cjshort/devonite)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the founders of [Codeship](https://codeship.io).

It looks like you're using a Ruby version that is currently not supported on Codeship. Could you send us an in-app support request with more info so we can take a look at your build directly.